# How to print second best move in python-chess, along with first bes move

Tags: python-3.x, python-chess

I'm currently trying to create a program using Python-Chess that will analyse games for me, and give a list of best, and second best moves. Even though lichess.org and chess.com have good UI for this, I want to mass analyse games and then output the data so I can graph or smth.

Right now, I've been able to open and store lists of games, and analyse the best move, but how do I get it to output the second best move? Should be noted I'm a beginner and am struggling big time understand what all the classes and functions do.

Code:

```
import chess
import asyncio
import chess.engine
import chess.pgn

engine = chess.engine.SimpleEngine.popen_uci("filelocation")
board = chess.Board()
pgnBase = open("filelocation")
gameList = []

#Accesses the files and stores each game in a list of objects
temp = chess.pgn.read_game(pgnBase)
while str(type(temp)) != "<class 'NoneType'>":
    gameList.append(temp.mainline_moves())
    temp = chess.pgn.read_game(pgnBase)

temp = gameList[0]
analysis = []
for moves in temp:
    result = engine.play(board, chess.engine.Limit(time=0.3))
    board.push(moves)
    analysis.append(str(result.move))
print(analysis)
engine.quit()
pgnBase.close()
```

Basically, I want it to output the second best move, along with the first.

Comment: Highly unlikely that the engine keeps track of that out of the box. There could be several moves with the same score as the best one, or else several with the same inferior score.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. This is not a code-writing or tutoring service. It is not possible to provide a specific answer without you providing sufficient information to understand your problem. Please see: [Why is Can someone help me? not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)  for more details.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.